# How can I increase the effectiveness of my bathroom vent fan?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

The vent fan in my bathroom isn't very effective.  After taking a shower, the bathroom takes several hours to dry out.

The fan itself works fine: it generates almost enough static suction to hold a magazine against the ceiling.  I think the issue is the airflow path within the bathroom: since the fan is close to the door, dry air goes in the door, out the vent, and never mixes with the humid air in the shower stall.

How can I fix this?  My options for re-arranging the bathroom are limited: I'm in a condo, and any work that involves the ceiling or a structural wall needs to be cleared with the condo association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m no expert and just throwing out an idea but a small portable fan that directs the warmer air towards where the ceiling fan is could work.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  The quickest way to dry an area is air movement. Either a small fan to move the air around or diverting the dry air away from the exhaust fan.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about a simple piece of duck work to "move over" the suction of the exhaust fan? 
The periscope duct shown below was included in a question about dryer venting but got me thinking something like this might work. One end is put over the fan and the other end over the shower. I'm not suggesting this piece would work but the idea might. You could fabricate something similar out of sheets of Styrofoam ... just an idea before my coffee.
[image]