# Should I trim my bathroom door to improve air extraction?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, exhaust-fan, uk

### Current situation

My bathroom looks like this:

[image: bathroom plan + pictures]

The problem is that I face some mild humidity issues (on ceiling and tile grout), as it is difficult to extract air after having taken a shower.
Indeed, it happens that the door is virtually air-tight.

This makes that none of the ventilating strategies below is really effective:

| Strategy | Extractor fan | Window | Door | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | on | closed | closed | Fan is not powerful enough to suck enough air through the door, so the flow doesn't seem sufficient to prevent condensation on walls and ceiling. |
| 2 | off | open | closed | Usually not sufficient enough, plus is a bit of an issue in winter as the dormer window can't be open/closed easily (too high); plus leaving it open constantly isn't very pleasant in the morning). |
| 3 | off | closed | open | Humidity goes in the flat, and low air circulation within the bathroom makes that there is still condensation. |
| 4 | on | open | closed | The air extracted by the fan… is mostly that that just entered through the window, so it's not effective. |
| 5 | on | closed | ajar | Works, but the sound of the fan — despite being not very loud — is bothering as the bedroom & home office are located right in front of the bathroom, so still not optimal. |
| 6 | off | open | ajar | Most effective solution, yet leads to draught and slamming doors ; plus isn't really possible during winter months. |

So I think that strategy #1 would be ideal… should the hallway ￫ bathroom air flow be greater.
I don't think a more powerful extractor fan would be of much help *in the current configuration*… plus it's likely to be even noisier.

### Questions:

1. Would trimming the bottom of the door (to let more air from the hallway in) be a good idea?
2. If so, how much should I trim?
3. Would a circular saw (with a guide) be the right tool to do it?

Comment: How humid is the house?  When do you turn the fan on?  Have you checked if the fan and duct is clean?   This link might give some more ideas.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/175284/how-can-i-increase-the-effectiveness-of-my-bathroom-vent-fan?rq=1

Comment: @crip659 1/ The house is globally sound and dry. 2/ I turn the fan when I enter the bathroom. It can take a good few hours (with fan on/door closed) for most of the humidity to be extracted. 3/ Except a bit of dust and some light cobweb, the duct is unobstructed and the air can flow freely. I've cleaned the fan. 4/ Thanks for your comment and the link.

Comment: I have also considered removing/thining the skirting board (that is taller than floor level), but 1/ I'm not sure it's a good idea and 2/ I can't seem to be able to remove it without damaging it (or the flooring on either side).

Comment: The fan is close to the door.  Most extra air coming though the door will go right to the fan and not help much.   Think a small fan to move the air around the room will help more.

Comment: A door air vent near the bottom of the door would look better than a gap under the door.

Comment: @crip659 I'm sorry my plan isn't clear, but the extractor fan (red) is much closer to the window (top, blue) than the door (bottom, brown). Actually, an air flow from below the door to the extractor would be quite ideal, as it would roughly go from floor-bottom-left to ceiling-top-right corner of the room. It's sure it's not a big room, so any corner are close to the others anyway! I'm actively considering a battery powered small ventilator, though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would like to minimise the visual impact indeed, and assumed that trimming a few mils (should that do the job) would be less noticeable than a air vent grille. Plus as all doors in the flat are the same model and solid wood, I'd like to “damage” them as little as possible. But things like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/460x135mm-18-1x5-3inch-Ventilation-Quality-Plastic/dp/B00DDTV9IW) could well be the “least bad” solution.

Comment: @ebosi  My mistake, was looking at the silver square above window and mistook it as a vent cover.  The door vent does seem like a good choice, since you could probably place a filter in it, to muffler any extra noise a bit.

Comment: yes it would help, sounds like it wouldn't take much to multiply the inflow volume.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell what's above the room, but if possible, a ceiling vent would be a good idea. As far away from the fan as possible - and it wouldn't look out of place, would save the door, and be simple to change with a piece of plasterboard later if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion — I'm sorry I didn't mentioned I live in an appartment, so drilling through floor/ceiling is not an option in my situation.